# Prompt User to Select/Create Datasource Item when inserting Rendering via Page Editor

Tags: sitecore, datasource, page-editor, sitecore8.1

Using Sitecore 8.1 - I [used these instructions](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/prompt-user-to-selectcreate-datasource-item-when-inserting-rendering-via-page-editor/) to be open the datasource item create/select when adding a rendering via the page editor but only the Control Properties comes up. I've managed to successfully do this in 7.5 but nothing happens in 8.1.

[image]

Is this an issue for anyone else?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue - the 'Data Source' underneath the Data tab must be empty while 'Datasource Location' and 'Datasource Template' have to be populated.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer so that it can help others :)